# How to implement export nad import orders data in Prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to migrate **customer orders** all data from old Prestashop 1.3 to new Prestashop 1.6.

Im intermediate presta developer and it is not trivial problem for me, I did not found any module or tutorial to manage this issue. Orders data in presta mySQL are separated in over a dozen tables, differences between version 1.3 and 1.6 couses additional compatibility problem. Amount of data is not a problem its small shop.

**I want to know, how do you manage such issue?**

I have few ideas but no one sounds enough good:

1. Export data to csv, make compabile to 1.6 and then import (by php script or import from csv to mysql).
2. Make php script that reads old data from db, makes data compatibile and then insert to new shop db.

Both of this ideas are very time expensive, maybe someone have better idea/link/solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen such a free module to import customer orders or ..
I my self imported categories and products from one none familiar cms to presta shop 1.6
in presta 1.6 back office if you make the entity you want to import it has a menu at te right side which says which fields should be in csv file you generate for importing.
if your csv file does not match you should get the csv file in a language (like php) and then parse the file and generate appropriate csv file to import in prestashop.

importing data with csv file is the easier job I think.
after uploading csv file for importing presta ask you that each column you have in your csv file is elated to which column of your presta system.

Comment: ok, thanks, I solved my problemy by custom import/export scripts directly between 2 prestashop's databases.

Comment: Could you post your script?

Answer (score 0):

This php script has 4 functions.

- getHeader() function get header of CSV file as an array.
- getCategories() fetch categories name from CSV file again as an array.
- getRecords() function get all records (excludes header) as an two dimensional array.

```
<?php

function getHeader()
{
    $filename  = "past_cms_csv_file.csv";
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
    $records = explode('EOREOR', $contents);
    $header = explode(';', $records[0]);
    array_splice($header, count($header)-1, 1);
    return $header; 
}


function getCategories()
{
    $header = getHeader();
    $index = array_search('v_categories_name_1_4', $header);
    $filename  = "past_cms_csv_file.csv";
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
    $records = explode('EOREOR', $contents);
    $cats = array();

    for($i=1;$i<count($records);$i++)
    {
        $record = $records[$i];
        $items = explode('";"', $record);
        array_push($cats,$items[$index] );
    }
    $newCats = array_unique($cats);


    $mycats = [];
    foreach($newCats as $cat)
    {
        array_push($mycats, $cat);
    }
    array_splice($mycats, count($mycats)-1 , 1);
    return $mycats;
}

function getRecords()
{
    $filename  = "past_cms_csv_file.csv";
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
    $records = explode('EOREOR', $contents);
    $header = getHeader();
    $index = array_search('v_categories_name_1_4', $header);
    $cats = getCategories();

    for($i=1;$i<count($records);$i++)
    {
        $record = $records[$i];
        $items = explode('";"', $record);
        array_push($cats,$items[$index] );


        for($j=0;$j<count($items);$j++)
        {
            $results[$i][$j] = $items[$j];
        }
    }   

    return $results;
}

function makecsvfile($filename , $start_index)
{
    $header = getHeader();
    $results = getRecords();
    $active_index = array_search('v_status', $header);
    $name_index = array_search('v_products_name_4', $header);
    $desc_index = array_search('v_products_description_4', $header);
    $meta_title_index = array_search('v_products_meta_title_4', $header);
    $meta_keywords_index = array_search('v_products_meta_keywords_4', $header);
    $meta_desc_index = array_search('v_products_meta_description_4', $header);
    $price_index = array_search('v_products_price', $header);
    $quantity_index = array_search('v_products_quantity', $header);
    $category_index = array_search('v_categories_name_1_4', $header);
    $subcategory_index = array_search('v_categories_name_2_4', $header);


    $string  = '';
    $string .= '"ID";"Active";"Name";"Description";"Meta_title";"Meta_keywords";"Meta_Description";"Categories";"Quantity";"tax_rule";"Price";"Image URLs"';
    $string .= PHP_EOL;

    for($i=1;$i<count($results);$i++)
    {
        if( $results[$i][$category_index] != 'Schoenen en sokjes'  &&
            $results[$i][$category_index] != 'Accessoires meisjes' &&
            $results[$i][$category_index] != 'Accessoires jongens' &&
            $results[$i][$category_index] != 'Communie -en doopkleding' &&
            $results[$i][$category_index] != 'Aanbiedingen'
            )
            {
                $string .= '"';
                $string .= $i+$start_index;
                $string .= '";"';
                if($results[$i][$active_index] == 'Active')
                    $string .= 1;
                else if($results[$i][$active_index] == 'Inactive')
                    $string .= 0;   
                $string .= '";"';
                $string .= $results[$i][$name_index];
                $string .= '";"';
                $string .= $results[$i][$desc_index];
                $string .= '";"';
                $string .= $results[$i][$meta_title_index];
                $string .= '";"';
                if(strlen($results[$i][$meta_keywords_index]) < 255)
                    $string .= $results[$i][$meta_keywords_index];
                else
                {
                    $meta_key_words = substr($results[$i][$meta_keywords_index],0,254);
                    $last_comma_pos = strrpos($meta_key_words , ',');
                    $meta_key_words = substr($meta_key_words,0,$last_comma_pos);
                    $string .= $meta_key_words;
                }
                $string .= '";"';
                $string .= $results[$i][$meta_desc_index];
                $string .= '";"';

                if($results[$i][$subcategory_index] == '' && 
                    $results[$i][$category_index] != 'Tiara\'s & Kroontjes' &&
                    $results[$i][$category_index] != 'Feest / Gala jurken' &&
                    $results[$i][$category_index] != 'Ringkussens' &&
                    $results[$i][$category_index] != 'Bolero\'s en Jasjes')
                    $string .= $results[$i][$category_index];

                else if($results[$i][$category_index] == 'Tiara\'s & Kroontjes')
                    $string .= 'Kroontjes, diademen & tiara\'s';

                else if($results[$i][$category_index] == 'Feest / Gala jurken')
                    $string .= 'Feest- en galajurken';          

                else if($results[$i][$category_index] == 'Ringkussens')
                    $string .= 'kado kussens';

                else if($results[$i][$category_index] == 'Bolero\'s en Jasjes')
                    $string .= 'Bolero’s & jasjes';         

                else 
                    $string .= $results[$i][$subcategory_index];
                $string .= '";"';

                $string .= $results[$i][$quantity_index];
                $string .= '";"';

                $string .= 53;
                $string .= '";"';
                $string .= $results[$i][$price_index];
                $string .= '";"';
                $string .= 'http://example.com/path/to/myimage.jpg';        
                $string .= '"';
                $string .= PHP_EOL;
            }
    }
    file_put_contents($filename, $string);
}

makecsvfile('products.csv' , 100);
?>
```